# Proving Green's First Theorem for the Laplace-Beltrami

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian, greens-theorem, lie-derivative

${\bf W.t.s:}$

I'd like to show for the generalised Laplacian defined on a compact, connected orientable n dimensional Riemannian manifold ($M, g$) ie. for $\Delta u = $div ($\nabla u$) that

$$\int_M u\Delta u = -\int_M {\lvert \nabla u \rvert}^2$$

${\bf Attempt:}$

I've tried using the identity

$$\mbox{div} (X) \Omega = \mathcal{L}_{X} \Omega$$

on $X = \nabla u$ and where $\Omega$ is the Riemannian volume form. This gives:

$$\int_M u\Delta u \Omega = \int_M u \mbox{div} (\nabla u)\Omega = \int_M u\mathcal{L}_{\nabla u} \Omega \underset{Cartan}{=} \int_M ud(i_{\nabla u} \Omega) + ui_{\nabla u}(d\Omega)$$.

It is here where I get stuck. There may well be a more efficient way of showing this so please feel free to suggest alternative methods.

In Euclidean space I know this would be a standard integration by parts. But I presume this is out of the question given that we are in a more general setting.

Comment: Are you familiar with the divergence theorem in this setting? Once you have that, you can proceed more or less exactly as you would in Euclidean space.

Comment: Not in this setting, no. I can't quite see how we're in a position to use the divergence theorem. Surely the presence of the $u$ multiplying the $\Delta u$ means we don't have an exact divergence?

Comment: It's not exact, but you still have the product rule $\operatorname{div}(fX)=f\operatorname{div}X+\langle\operatorname{grad} f,X\rangle$, so you can integrate by parts.

Comment: I often will verify an identity like this using local coordinates and then convert the proof back into coordinate-free notation. But the key facts are $\int_M \nabla\cdot V\, dV_g = 0$ and the product rule for both the divergence of a function times a vector field, as cited by @Kajelad, and the gradient of the dot product of two vector fields.

Comment: This makes sense, and I can see it is pretty clear once I've used this product rule. But I guess my question is, does this product rule work for any Riemannian manifold with any metric? For example is your inner product the one given by the arbitrary metric $g$? Because @Deane you mention the dot product, which to me is a Euclidean result.

Comment: @JMill The dot $\cdot$, angle brackets $\langle\ ,\ \rangle$, etc. are all just alternate notation for the metric $g$ or the natural pairing between vectors and covectors. The product rule applies for any Riemannian manifold; proving it starting with the definition $\operatorname{div}X:=\nabla_aX^a$ is trivial; if you're instead using the definitions $\operatorname{div}(X)\Omega=\mathcal{L}_X\Omega$ or $\operatorname{div}(X)\Omega=d(\iota_X\Omega)$ it may require doing a bit of computation in local coordinates (all of these definitions are equivalent).

Comment: Sorry about that. I do like to write $X\cdot Y = g(X,Y) = g_{ij}X^iX^j$. The classical dot product is ill-defined on an abstract Riemannian manifold. On the other hand, if the Riemannian manifold is isometrically embedded into Euclidean space, then the Riemannian metric is literally equal to the dot product on the Euclidean space.